# Разбор HTTP-запроса

Tags: java, http

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как грамотно распарсить http-запрос, дабы фронт-контроллер смог определить тип запроса, и отдать его соответствующему обработчику?

```
private void readRequest() throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
    LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(
            new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

    String line = reader.readLine();

    while (!line.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(line);
        if (line.startsWith("GET")) {
            System.out.println("This is Get");
            IndexHandler indexHandler = new IndexHandler(inputStream, this.socket);
            indexHandler.handle();
}
```

Или другие варианты определения типа запросов! Т.к. получить байты и работать с ними - не верю я в это. Переводить в чары, а потом в строку? Тоже неясно. И как выходить из ситуации, если по хттп послали гигабайт данных? Фронт-контроллер тоже должен все считать? И последний вопрос - что передавать в `indexHandler` (у меня - обработчик метода `GET`).

Comment: Вы свой "Tomcat" пишете? :) Если нет, то есть же классы `servlet` и иже с ними.

Comment: Да, мини-томкат. Servlet использовать не могу

Comment: вбейте в гугл "java simple http server"

Answer (score 2):

В случае, если вы действительно хотите переделать по своему вещи, уже имплементированные в `UrlConnection`, то придется работать с байтами через соответствующий стрим. Разумеется, вы можете взять любую стороннюю реализацию `http` `parser'a`, однако в таком случае вопрос не имел бы смысла.

*Рекомендую изучить [**референс**](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/) по спецификации `http`, а также следующую [**реализацию `http` парсера.**](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Network-Protocol/HttpParser.htm)*

---

P.S *Гигабайт данных просто просплиттится и будет обработан фрагментами.*

Comment: Я не пойму, зачем работать напрямую с байтами, если можно перегнать байты в строку и из строки извлекать нужные ключи? И что, в таком случае, нужно передавать обработчику?

Comment: Наверное читать по строкам проще. Тут важно понять, куда складывать и как передать программе-обработчику (например POST) данные запроса.